# file not found exception from FileReader

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

sorry for this dumb question. but i am really not able to find where i am doing wrong. please help. i am trying to parse a file using JSON. file is there in the system too. but it is showing filenotfound exception. and its really frustrating.

snippet of my code is below :

```
        System.out.println("Please provide JSON file path : ");
        filePathJson = "\"D:\\files\\test.xlsx\"";
                //in.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please provide Excel file path : ");
        filePathExcel = in.nextLine();

        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(filePathJson));
        System.out.println("hii");

        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
```

and error I am getting :

```
Please provide JSON file path : 
Please provide Excel file path : 
"D:\\files\\test1.xlsx"
java.io.FileNotFoundException: "D:\files\test.xlsx" (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:137)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:96)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at JavaJsonSplitter.main(JavaJsonSplitter.java:50)
```

Can somebody point me where i am doing wrong.

please ignore one useless sysout.

Answer (score 4):

You're actually putting quotes in the filename. Remove them, you would only need actual quotes around it on the command line and such. When you're giving a filename to `FileReader` (or any other method that expects a filename, not a command line), you just give the filename (even if it has spaces in it).

E.g.,

```
filePathJson = "\"D:\\files\\test.xlsx\"";
```

becomes

```
filePathJson = "D:\\files\\test.xlsx";
```

Comment: did it...changed both files hard coded and given as u suggested.. still facing same issue...

Comment: @user2696466: You may be facing another issue with the filename, but not the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the extra double quotes surrounding the file path. That is not required at all.

```
filePathJson = "D:\\files\\test.xlsx";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
filePathJson = "\"D:\\files\\test.xlsx\"";
```

Should be like

```
filePathJson = "D:\\files\\test.xlsx";
```

Answer (score 0):

@user2696466 -

please see the revise code see if it works

```
System.out.println("Please provide JSON file path : ");
    **filePathJson = "D:/files/test.xlsx/"**
            //in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please provide Excel file path : ");
    filePathExcel = in.nextLine();

    Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader(filePathJson));
    System.out.println("hii");

    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
```

Comment: For a useful answer, always say **what** you've changed and **why**. (And don't introduce syntax errors for emphasis.)

Answer (score 0):

The clue is here

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: "D:\files\test.xlsx" (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

Try this

```
filePathJson = "D:\\files\\test.xlsx";
```